# trouble with python manage.py migrate -> No module named psycopg2

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2, migrate

I am having some trouble with migrating Django using postgresql.

This is my first time with Django, and I am just following the tutorial.

As suggested on the Django website, I have created a virtualenv to run the Django project.

Next, I created a postgresql database with these settings:

[image]

In settings.py I have set these values for the database:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'django_tutorial',
        'USER': 'johan',
        'PASSWORD': '1234',
    }
}
```

When installing psycopg2 with apt-get I get this message:

```
(venv)johan@johan-pc:~/sdp/django_tutorial/venv/django_tutorial$ sudo apt-get install python-psycopg2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-psycopg2 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 95 not upgraded.
```

As far as I can tell this would mean that psycopg2 is installed.

When running

```
$python manage.py migrate
```

I get the following error message:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named psycopg2
```

If needed for the answer I could provide the entire stack trace.

Could someone explain what I could do to solve this? I have also looked on Google for a solution with no luck.

Comment: Have you tried `pip install psycopg2` inside your virtualenv?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python-psycopg2` installs psycopg2 in your system level python not in your virtualenv you will have to install it in your virutalenv to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It must be because you are installing psycopg2 in your system level python installation not in your virtualenv.

```
sudo apt-get install python-psycopg2
```

will install it in your system level python installation.

You can install it in your virtualenv by

```
pip install psycopg2
```

after activating your virtualenv or you can create your virtualenv with `--system-site-packages` flag so that your virtualenv will have packages in your system level python already available.

```
virtualenv --system-site-packages test
```

where `test` is your virtualenv.

Answer (score 1):

[Psycopg](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/) is the most popular PostgreSQL database adapter for the Python programming language.
I was also facing a similar problem when I tried to run the migration with Postgresql database. The below step worked for me fine.

Activate your Virtual Environment and run the following command

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

Now try running `python manage.py migrate`

Answer (score 0):

It's because you use Django in a python virtualenv and as stated on [virtualenv web site](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) :

> It creates an environment that has its own installation directories,
>   that doesn’t share libraries with other virtualenv environments (and
>   optionally doesn’t access the globally installed libraries either).

That means that you need to install psycopg2 in your virtualenv and not globaly or make it access globaly installed libraries.