# ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named 'psycopg2'

Tags: django, psycopg2, django-migrations

I have a problem with migration with my Django project.
I run in the command line

```
python3 manage.py migrate
```

For some reasons I got the error

```
ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named 'psycopg2'
```

But I have checked the psycopg2 installation and it seems that it is ok

```
(myenv) (base) Elenas-MacBook-Air:myenv elenaorlova$ pip install 
psycopg2==2.7.5
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 
1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer 
maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 
2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at 
https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release- 
process/#python-2-support
Requirement already satisfied: psycopg2==2.7.5 in 
./lib/python2.7/site-packages (2.7.5)
```

Do you know what could be the reason of this problem? I already re-installed psycopg2 several times, including manual. Will be very thankful for any help!

Comment: Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33237669/7659834)?

Comment: @kamilyrb yes, just now. It says that `sudo: apt-get: command not found`. And when I tried to install pyscog2 once again it gave me `Requirement already satisfied: psycopg2 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (2.7.5)`

Comment: Are you using python3 and your venv runs python2.7?

Comment: `sudo  apt-get` this command about linux. I think your os is macos. So you cannot use this command. Also there is a problem about your python versions. you used python3 in your migrate command. So if you use python3 you must install psycop2 with pip3: `pip3 install psycopg2 `

Comment: @kamilyrb thank you very much. Is there any chance to upgrade python version in venv without removing the existing one?

Comment: I think you have already version 3. You must only add 3 after python and pip commands for using v3.Actually  I have never use venv, but I think [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/manage-multiple-python-versions-and-virtual-environments-venv-pyenv-pyvenv-a29fb00c296f/) document can help you.

Comment: Don’t try to upgrade Python on the virtual environment, just create a new one. Once you have activated a virtual environment, you shouldn’t need to use `python3` or `pip3` - just use `python` and `python -m pip`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Do instead:

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```